# Semantics of reducer and combiner in PLINQ

Tags: .net, plinq, reducers

Inspired by Clojure 1.5's `reducers` library, I've been playing with making PLINQ's `ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate()` method behave the same way. For the most part, it very straightforwardly does.

There's one possible behavior difference that I suspect may exist, though. In [Igor Ostrovsky's blog post about the 2007 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/01/24/7211660.aspx), he claims that `combineAccumulatorsFunc` has to be commutative. The modern documentation doesn't seem to say anything about it having to be commutative, and I haven't been able to force it to do anything that depends on commutativity, but I also haven't been able to force it to do anything that depends on associativity.

**Main question:** Are the semantics of `combineAccumulatorsFunc` defined anywhere? Even if not, am I going to be okay assuming that it may be called associatively but not commutatively?

I'm using the following LINQPad snippet to try to cause out-of-order `combineAccumulatorsFunc` invocations:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0,1000000).AsUnordered().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).
        WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism).
        Aggregate<int,IImmutableList<int>,IEnumerable<int>>(
  () => { Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(5000)); return ImmutableList<int>.Empty; },
  (L,n) => n % 2 == 0 ? L.Add(n) : L,
  (L1,L2) => {new {L1 = L1.First(),L2 = L2.First()}.Dump("partition"); return L1.Concat(L2).ToImmutableList();},
  x => x.AsEnumerable()
).Dump();
```